# Dependency vs Artifact gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

While reading configuration doc [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) I came across this line

> `Configuration` is an instance of a `FileCollection` that contains all
>   dependencies (see also `Configuration.getAllDependencies()`) but not
>   artifacts

I am just unable to understand how `artifacts` and `dependencies` differ?